# Read error near the end of a file I'm downloading - what's at fault?

Tags: download, http, wget, file-download

I'm trying to download the updated firmware for some device (it's a Belkin Network Exentder, but that's inconsequential). I manage to get to 97% of it, seeing:

```
$  wget -c --verbose http://networking.belkin.com/update/files/F9K1015/v1/WW/F9K1015_WW_1.00.08.bin
--2018-04-14 18:56:03--  http://networking.belkin.com/update/files/F9K1015/v1/WW/F9K1015_WW_1.00.08.bin
Resolving networking.belkin.com (networking.belkin.com)... 67.20.177.190
Connecting to networking.belkin.com (networking.belkin.com)|67.20.177.190|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2289666 (2.2M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘F9K1015_WW_1.00.08.bin’

F9K1015_WW_1.00.08.bin       97%[========================================>  ]   2.12M  --.-KB/s    eta 1s
```

and then it gets stuck for a while. If I stop and retry, I get:

```
$ wget -c --verbose http://networking.belkin.com/update/files/F9K1015/v1/WW/F9K1015_WW_1.00.08.bin
--2018-04-14 18:55:22--  http://networking.belkin.com/update/files/F9K1015/v1/WW/F9K1015_WW_1.00.08.bin
Resolving networking.belkin.com (networking.belkin.com)... 67.20.177.190
Connecting to networking.belkin.com (networking.belkin.com)|67.20.177.190|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

Who's having a read error? Me? the Belkin HTTP server? Someplace else? Should I presume to tell Belkin that their storage is messed up? The connection I'm on is kind of choppy (which is why I'm trying to update the firmware to begin with...)

Comment: I can replicate the issue. My router is a custom Debian machine, my connection is fine.

Comment: Replicated on Windows using wget binaries... This is weird